# Sometimes laravel calls another route instead of real one

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

In laravel `routes.php` file, I have below code:

```php
// User Resourceful Routing
Route::resource('user','UserController');
```

By default `delete` route goes to `show` method of `UserController`. To overcome this problem I have written this route in laravel `routes.php`:

```php
// Delete Users Route
Route::get('user/{user}/{flag}', ['uses' => 'UserController@destroy', 'as'=>'user.destroy'])->before('permission:user_delete');
```

Still It works fine for me but sometimes (2 out of 10 times) it goes to `show` method of `UserController` instead of `destroy` method.

```php
// Destroy method
public function destroy($id,$flag='normal'){
}
```

Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: When using resource controllers, you *must* use the correct HTTP method, such as `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`. If you don't pecify the `DELETE` method in your request, Laravel will think you're working with the `GET` method, and will call `show()` instead of `destroy()`.

Comment: @MikeRockett: I know this but via API you can select delete method but there is no delete method for browser. When you make request via browser then this problem arises.

Comment: It happens sometimes only. Other times it is working fine for me.

Comment: you would have to use a form with a hidden _method=delete and method=post to send a delete request via the web browser, via method spoofing.

Comment: lagbox is correct, method spoofing is the way to go if you are not using AJAX.

Comment: I am using AJAX and problem is functionality was implemented 6 months ago and till yesterday it was working fine. now suddenly this problem is arose.

Comment: If you are using AJAX, then `DELETE` *must* be available to you. Please update your answer with the JS code you are using.

Comment: And why did you revert my edits? They were correct.

Comment: @Mike Rockett:- I want to highlight that Problem is occurs only sometimes.

Comment: I don't understand how that is possible. If you are passing the correct request and routing correctly, then the process will *always* remain the same. If it is 'sometimes' doing this, then there is something wrong with the code you use to make the request. Also, you are using a `before` filter, which is no longer available in Laravel 5 - you must use middleware instead.

Comment: @MikeRockett: I have told you in comment that I am using Laravel 4.

Comment: Then that's fine, but it doesn't change the fact that something is wrong in your code, which you don't appear to be willing to share, as I asked in a previous comment. Simple fact is that you must use the `DELETE` method when using AJAX, or method spoofing if you are not using AJAX. If your code is correct, then Laravel will *always* call the correct method. Simple as that.

Comment: @MikeRockett: Ajax DELETE is working fine for me now but still dont't know the exact issue. anyway functionality is working by new way. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use 'delete' method instead of get.

You can use in laravel like this.

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['UserController@destroy', $user->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
  {!! Form::submit('Delete User') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And if you are using ajax you can use like this .

```
$.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: 'users/' + user_id,
        success: function(affectedRows) {
        }
    });
```

If you dont want to use laravel's default destroy method then you can use delete_user method with post action.

Comment: There is no delete method for browser. laravel delete method works only for API.

Comment: DELETE method is not globally available for all browsers. even jQuery official documentation not show such kind of method in ajax. anyway thanks for your answer +1.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `Form` is not longer available in Laravel. You need to download a separate package for that. Your answer should contain the raw code, including the method spoofing (`<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">`).

Comment: @MikeRockett: It supports until you have choosen to migrate to Laravel 5. My project is still in version 4. So everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

explicitly define your routes instead of using a resource after all they are 3 or 4. besides the destroy method.

i however would start by debug the current routes  by `php artisan route:list` and check your endpoints. likely you are missing a parameter somewhere when sending a request.

Comment: I had tried it bother. I had run php artisan routes and got all routes. Thanks for your suggestion. This is the first step I had done.